# How to know which Layout type is a View in?

Tags: android

I want to extend a View to create a custom View, and automatically force some layout parameters, this way:

```
public class myView extends View {
    public myView(Context context) {
       this.setLayoutParameters(LayoutParameters(LayoutParameters.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParameters.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
}
```

My problem is, how can I set the LayoutParameters if I don't know if the view will be set inside a LinearLayout, a RelativeLayout or somewhere else?
How can I detect which Layout type is the view in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout parameters you're talking about all come from `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams` which is common to all the `ViewGroup` classes (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.)

So you shouldn't need to distinguish between the parent view types; just use the `LayoutParams` directly.

Comment: Oh thank you, so I have to 'import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams' and all is done! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an easy solution by myself. The question anyway remains valid as soon as there may be a easier and more complete way to do the same thing.

```
    if (this.getParent() instanceof LinearLayout)
        this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```